# Databinding logic: Evals and the AND/OR statements with commas

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out some databinding logic that's being used to set the visible boolean on a asp panel.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelTimerDisplay" runat="server" 
 Visible='<%# If(((Eval("IsPHAdjustmentPhase") = True Or 
 Eval("IsPHAdjustmentBOM") = True) And 
 Eval("StepTimerValueRequired") = True And Eval("NoInitialAdjustmentValueRecorded") = 0), 
 Eval("ESignRecordedEnabled") Or Eval("ESignAddedEnabled") Or Eval("ESignCompletedEnabled"), 
 Eval("StepTimerValueRequired") And Eval("StepRequirementsMet"))%>'>
```

What does it mean when you have this : `eval = value AND eval2  = value, eval3 = value`

Does the comma in between `eval2 = value, eval3 = value` indicate another AND statement?

Comment: The comma is part of the [If Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx).

Comment: So if it's TRUE, FALSE then it's FALSE?